# Drawing districts on city map using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am quite new to ArcGIS.

I am trying to create district level maps of all 81 cities in Turkey. There have been lots of new districts recently, so I feel like I have to draw these manually to make them up to date. I have ArcGIS 10.1.

What would be the best way to draw districts on the individual city maps? I already know the boundaries and shapes of each district, but I just need to have them in SHP format.

Answer (score 1):

well first you should decide if you want them in a shape file or a feature class.  A feature class would give you more flexability and options like enforcing topology.  If you have maps of the new districts, in an edit session, you can either draw them into your featureclass/shapefile using the edit and draw tools in arc.  Of course this would first require you to create the type of feature class you want (poly, line, etc) and the attributes to go along with it .The other option (similar setup before and in an edit session) is you could scan the images then geo-reference them (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHtxbpboDro) then take the images and trace the new districts onto the georeferenced layer.

Comment: Thank you for getting back! So, let me be more precise: Suppose I have a map like this: 

https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullan%C4%B1c%C4%B1:The_Emirr/TE%C3%9CB#/media/File:Adana_location_districts.svg

Is it possible to make arc gis recognize these boundarties and associate each of these districts with the name on it? After all, what I want it to be able to shade these districts based on some simple data. Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course you can do that.  Do you have a shapefile or featureclass of the study area which shows those administrative boundaries? If so you will simply add a field to the shapefile/featureclass , then put the attributes in you want to classify the districts on, then goto symbology in your table of content and choose catagories and then select the newly created field you just made.  Arc will then color each district differently depending on the attribute in the new field.